# Python - else statement is never triggered

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I would expect this to be a duplicate question, yet I couldn't find an answer. I'm sorry.

I have written a simple function that's supposed to return either an empty string or a string of one character. Sometimes, however, it returns **None.** Even though it *should* match one of the operands and, in case it doesn't, still output a string.

```
baseconvert = digits+ascii_lowercase+"0"
def checker(operand, factorlist): # hardcoded interpreter of the calculus converted in base 10. i is equal to the base.
    if (operand == '+'):
        if (factorlist[0] + factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif (operand == '-'):
        if (factorlist[0] - factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif (operand == '*'):
        if (factorlist[0] * factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif (operand == '/'):
        if (factorlist[0] / factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    else:
        return ""
```

So while typing this post I figured out I could just remove the else statement:

```
    # else: is not necessary
    return ""
```

works fine. I still wonder, however, why this else statement is never triggered.

P.S.: Is there a cleaner way to just interpret the string, for example "*10 - 7 = 3*" to get a boolean result? I'm relatively new to python and couldn't come up with anything.

## EDIT:

The following code, with parameters taken out of context, prints None:

```
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase
baseconvert = digits+ascii_lowercase+"0"

def checker(operand, factorlist): # hardcoded interpreter of the calculus converted in base 10. i is equal to the base.
    if (operand == '+'):
        if (factorlist[0] + factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif (operand == '-'):
        if (factorlist[0] - factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif (operand == '*'):
        if (factorlist[0] * factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif (operand == '/'):
        if (factorlist[0] / factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            return baseconvert[i]
    else:
        return ""
i=17
print(checker('+', [1987,222,2227]))
```

What was expected:

- `if (operand == "+")` is True.
- `if (factorlist[0] + factorlist[1] == factorlist[2])` is False.
- `else:` on line 15 is called.
- "" is returned.

I still wonder why this behavior I expected isn't shown, but no matter. Using just one return statement as well as leaving the `else:` away are great solutions.

I also found the following works, which is closest to what I was trying to accomplish:

```
def checker(operand, factorlist): # hardcoded interpreter of the calculus converted in base 10. i is equal to the base.
    if ((operand == '+') & (factorlist[0] + factorlist[1] == factorlist[2])):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif ((operand == '-') & (factorlist[0] - factorlist[1] == factorlist[2])):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif ((operand == '*') & (factorlist[0] * factorlist[1] == factorlist[2])):
            return baseconvert[i]
    elif ((operand == '/') & (factorlist[0] / factorlist[1] == factorlist[2])):
            return baseconvert[i]
    else:
        return ""
```

I've timed all solutions multiple times, and this final solution seems to be about 15% faster than having split if statements and using a variable with one return.

Comment: What do you mean by  _this else statement is never triggered_, because it will be triggered if operand is not a valid operator.

Comment: Please add an example that shows how you call the function and why it does not behave like you would want it to.

Comment: The reason your function sometimes returns `None` is because you don't always find a condition which results in a `return`.  When it drops out of your  outer `if` without a `return` then it will just fall through to the function end and give the default return value.

Comment: The `&` is **not** a logical operator in python, it is a *binary* operator.  You probably mean `and`.

Answer (score 2):

You have `if` clauses nested in your parent `if...elif`, when control does not flow out of those, it does not return to the parent `else` (i.e. if the function is not exited via any of the nested *if*s, execution completes at the end of the function). You should add a return at the end of your function to properly handle this and avoid returning the default `None`:

```
def checker(operand, factorlist):
    if operand == '+':
        if (factorlist[0] + factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            ...
    elif operand == '-':
        if (factorlist[0] - factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            ...
    elif operand == '*':
        if (factorlist[0] * factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            ...
    elif operand == '/':
        if (factorlist[0] / factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]):
            ...

    return ""
```

You can also safely remove the final `else` since the final return acts as a global return default in your function.

Comment: `when control does not flow out of those, it does not return to the parent else.`  
But does this matter if i have a return statement in every if like I do? I just need the function to terminate then by returning a character.

Answer (score 0):

It is subjective, but many will say only have one `return` in a function.  In this case that can help.  The problem is that you only return from each `elif` if another condition is True.  It can be refactored by something like this:

```
baseconvert = digits+ascii_lowercase+"0"
def checker(operand, factorlist):
    # hardcoded interpreter of the calculus converted in base 10. i is equal to the base.
    final_value = ""
    if operand == '+':
        if factorlist[0] + factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]:
            final_value = baseconvert[i]
    elif operand == '-':
        if factorlist[0] - factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]:
            final_value = baseconvert[i]
    elif operand == '*':
        if factorlist[0] * factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]:
            final_value = baseconvert[i]
    elif operand == '/':
        if factorlist[0] / factorlist[1] == factorlist[2]:
            final_value = baseconvert[i]

    return final_value
```

Note that you only need parentheses around a condition in python for precedence, most of the time they are not required.

Comment: What would be better? To write to a variable in the if statements and return this at the bottom of the function, or to return in every if-block like I tried to do now?

Comment: "Better" is subjective.  Personally I prefer the way I show, i.e. with a variable and only one `return`.  It might be a little more work initially, but it can make debugging and maintenance easier, particularly if you need to track the returned value.  However if using this pattern makes you jump through hoops then don't use it - it is *usually* better in my opinion but there can be exceptions.